# $x, y, z$ coordinates from velocity vector

Tags: vectors

so I have been given the question: $v=({19t^2i+2t^3j+(2t+5)k}) m/s$ where t is in seconds.

If the particle is at the origin when $t=0$ what is the x,y,z coordinates when $t=4$

I've used the acceleration magnitude formula at an earlier part of this question to find that so I have $a=180m/s^2$

I've no idea how to find the coordinates for position when $t=4$. I tried integrating the velocity vector equation to get the position vector equation but I'm well and truly stuck. Help please

Comment: is it $19t^2i$?

Comment: yeah it is, sorry i missed out the t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $v=$$dx\over dt$, you would need to integrate $v$ to get $x$.

Take each direction separately and solve.

Integrating $v$ , we get $x=($$19t^3\over 3$$i+$$t^4\over 2$$j+(t^2+5t)k + C)m$

Where C is the vector at $t=0$. So, $C=0$

Thus, just substitute $t=4$ in the above equation.

Comment: sorry for being a dunce, but could you expand further please?

Comment: @DerekKennington I edited my answer... Is it clear now?

Comment: I did that, and got the same answer, then i subbed in the numbers and came out with $404,128,36$ but that seems to be wrong

Comment: finally accepted my answer, it was my own fault, I had to input the answers to three significant figures so 36.0 not just 36, Thank-you very much for your help